# Open Google backup settings page programmatically

Tags: android, settings

Google settings are a submenu within Android settings in Android 6.0 and later.
I want to open the **Google Backup Settings** per intent.

This code opens the **Google Ads Settings**

```
String action = "com.google.android.gms.settings.ADS_PRIVACY";
    startActivity(new Intent(action));
```

How to open the **Google Backup Settings**?

Comment: Do you want to open this backup screen? https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7599404?key=2728c48fe8059b9e905fd109e0c5d333

Comment: yes, exactly that screen

Comment: I was able to open backup & Reset option using an intent after that clicking on "Backup" will take you the screen you want. Will that be helpful for you?  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7613152?key=5ce5654e28f81eae9c2693b5c4865c06

Comment: How did you open the Backup & Reset settings? Can you plzz post the intent code. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to open "Backup & Reset" screen using following function.

```
private void openBackUpAndReset(){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.gms", "com.google.android.gms.backup.component.BackupSettingsActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Which redirects to following screen.

[image: Backup & Reset]

I have Tested this on following devices:

1. Samsung M51(Android 11)
2. Pixel 3(Android 10)
3. Poco C3(Android 10)
4. Emulator(Android Lollipop)

Comment: Thank you! How did you find the name of that activity? Is there any way? I'm looking for ways to open other settings submenus.

Comment: @Brunni I actually did one of these two things if i remember correctly. 1) looking at the studio logcat when I manually click on settings screens & see what intent is called. Make sure you've "No filters" selected. 2) If first doesn't work then Go through the documentation where they mention package name & activity. This one is a bit hectic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
try {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.component = ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
        "com.android.settings.backup.UserBackupSettingsActivity")
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I figured this out by using Logcat in Android Studio & watching for the intent while I opened the settings & navigated to the Backup option.